# How do I get vertice data from google/bing maps?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, bing

I'm trying to develop a application that uses informations from google/bing maps, but I need the vertice data to recreate roads and I can't use images since I can't get road names and height info.

I need vertices/nodes of streets (with latitude,longitude,altitude, street name ) and no visual data.

Thanks.

Comment: Google Maps will only provide this data in a very roundabout way -- via Directions and decoding the route. You are also required to display a map if you use Google's API. You might be better off with OpenStreetMap data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Street Map is definitely the way to go for this - extracting vertex information from Bing/Google is both technically difficult, and a breach of the Terms of Use. OSM data is better quality in many cases and, more to the point, free to use under a CC-BY-SA licence.

You'll also probably need a spatial database in which to store the information. I've written a couple of articles about loading OSM data into SQL Server which you might find helpful. e.g.:
http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/loading-open-street-map-data-in-sql-server-part-ii-ways/

Comment: Thanks, you're article is very helpful!
Excellent work, thanks very much!